# Handling tables in ruby shoes framework

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, shoes

Could any one please tell me a nice tutorial regarding how to create edit and delete table in ruby shoes framework??

Comment: Hi Abhiram, this is probably not a good place to ask this question. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) for the sort of questions you should ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a table widget for Shoes. Have a look there http://hackety.com/users/kwicher/programs/table

Comment: ya i tried that table but i couldnt edit the content in that table when i click update..

Comment: you cannot directly edit the cells but you can access them programatically. In principle, it should be possible to modifiy the wighet so to youse textfields instead of labels.